# No me funciona un boton de una calculadora

Tags: javascript, html

Estoy haciendo una calculadora con *javascript*, *html* y *css*, pero tiene algunas funciones de una calculadora científica, por ejemplo, hace potencias, raíces y logaritmos.

En el último caso, hay un botón que no me funciona como debería, es el de logaritmo con base a elegir. La forma de usar es la siguiente, escribes un número, presionas `log(x)`, entonces vas a hacer logaritmo, con base el número que has escrito, después escribes otro número y presionas en igual.

Si el número 1 es 10 y el número 2 es 100, estarías haciendo logaritmo base 10 de 100, que debería dar 2, pues mi calculadora da 10, de hecho da el primer número que escribes, siempre.

He intentado ver si había puesto algo para que no funcionara pero no hay nada.

```js
    var numero1 = 0;
    var numero2 = 0;
    var signo = "";
    
    function inicio() {
        // Resultado
        var result = document.getElementById("result");
        
        // Numeros
        var cerocero = document.getElementById("cerocero");
        var cero = document.getElementById("cero");
        var uno = document.getElementById("uno");
        var dos = document.getElementById("dos");
        var tres = document.getElementById("tres");
        var cuatro = document.getElementById("cuatro");
        var cinco = document.getElementById("cinco");
        var seis = document.getElementById("seis");
        var siete = document.getElementById("siete");
        var ocho = document.getElementById("ocho");
        var nueve = document.getElementById("nueve");
    
        // Operaciones
        var suma = document.getElementById("suma");
        var resta = document.getElementById("resta");
        var multiplicacion = document.getElementById("multiplicacion");
        var division = document.getElementById("division");
        var resto = document.getElementById("resto");
        var raizCuadrada = document.getElementById("raizCuadrada");
        var raizX = document.getElementById("raizX");
        var cuadrado = document.getElementById("cuadrado");
        var cubo = document.getElementById("cubo");
        var elevadoX = document.getElementById("elevadoX");
        var logaritmo10 = document.getElementById("logaritmo10");
        var logaritmoNeperiano = document.getElementById("logaritmoNeperiano");
        var logaritmoX = document.getElementById("logaritmoX");
    
        // Igual y Reset
        var igual = document.getElementById("igual");
        var borrar = document.getElementById("borrar");
    
        // Mostrar en pantalla el boton que pulses
        cero.onclick = function(e) {
            result.textContent = result.textContent + "0";
        }
    
        cerocero.onclick = function(e) {
            result.textContent = result.textContent + "00";
        }
    
        uno.onclick = function(e) {
            result.textContent = result.textContent + "1";
        }
        
        dos.onclick = function(e) {
            result.textContent = result.textContent + "2";
        }
    
        tres.onclick = function(e) {
            result.textContent = result.textContent + "3";
        }
    
        cuatro.onclick = function(e) {
            result.textContent = result.textContent + "4";
        }
    
        cinco.onclick = function(e) {
            result.textContent = result.textContent + "5";
        }
    
        seis.onclick = function(e) {
            result.textContent = result.textContent + "6";
        }
    
        siete.onclick = function(e) {
            result.textContent = result.textContent + "7";
        }
    
        ocho.onclick = function(e) {
            result.textContent = result.textContent + "8";
        }
    
        nueve.onclick = function(e) {
            result.textContent = result.textContent + "9";
        }
    
        // Operaciones
        suma.onclick = function(e) {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = "+";
            limpiar();
        }
    
        resta.onclick = function(e) {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = "-";
            limpiar();
        }
    
        multiplicacion.onclick = function(e) {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = "*";
            limpiar();
        }
    
        division.onclick = function(e) {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = "/";
            limpiar();
        }
    
        resto.onclick = function(e) {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = "%";
            limpiar();
        }
    
        raizCuadrada.onclick = function(e) {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = "R2";
            resolver();
        }
    
        raizX.onclick = function(e) {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = "Rx";
            limpiar();
        }
    
        cuadrado.onclick = function(e) {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = "^2";
            resolver();
        }
    
        cubo.onclick = function(e) {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = "^3";
            resolver();
        }
    
        elevadoX.onclick = function(e) {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = "^x";
            limpiar();
        }
    
        logaritmo10.onclick = function(e) {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = "log10";
            resolver();
        }
    
        logaritmoNeperiano.onclick = function(e) {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = "loge";
            resolver();
        }
    
        logaritmoX.onclick = function(e) {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = "logX";
            limpiar();
        }
    
        // Igual y reset
        igual.onclick = function(e) {
            numero2 = result.textContent;
            resolver();
        }
    
        borrar.onclick = function(e) {
            resetearValores();
        }
    }
    
    function limpiar() {
        result.textContent = "";
    }
    
    function resetearValores() {
        result.textContent = "";
        numero1 = 0;
        numero2 = 0;
        signo = "";
    }
    
    function resolver() {
        var fin = 0;
    
        switch(signo) {
            case "+":
                fin = parseFloat(numero1) + parseFloat(numero2);
                break;
    
            case "-":
                fin = parseFloat(numero1) - parseFloat(numero2);
                break;
    
            case "*":
                fin = parseFloat(numero1) * parseFloat(numero2);
                break;
    
            case "/":
                fin = parseFloat(numero1) / parseFloat(numero2);
                break;
    
            case "%":
                fin = parseFloat(numero1) % parseFloat(numero2);
                break;
    
            case "R2":
                fin = Math.sqrt(numero1);
                break;
    
            case "Rx":
                fin = Math.pow(numero2, Math.pow(numero1, (-1)));
                break;
    
            case "^2":
                fin = Math.pow(numero1, 2);
                break;
    
            case "^3":
                fin = Math.pow(numero1, 3);
                break;
    
            case "^x":
                fin = Math.pow(numero1, numero2);
                break;
    
            case "log10":
                fin = Math.log10(numero1);
                break;
    
            case "loge":
                fin = Math.log(numero1);
                break;
    
            case "logX":
                function getBaseLog(x, y) {
                    return Math.log(y) / Math.log(x);
                }
    
                fin = getBaseLog(numero2, numero1);
    
            default:
                if(numero1 == 0) {
                    fin = numero2;
    
                } else {
                    fin = numero1;
                }
        }
        resetearValores();
        result.textContent = fin;
    }
```

```css
        .calculadora {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #14db2f;
        width: 400px;
        height: 600px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    
    .calculadora td button {
        display: block;
        width: 85px;
        height: 55px;
        font-size: 20px;
        box-align: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    #igual {
        height: 94px;
        width: 85px;
    }
    
    #cero {
        height: 35px;
        width: 174px;
    }
    
    #cerocero {
        height: 35px;
    }
    
    #result {
        display: block;
        font-size: 35px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        width:350px;
        height: 120px;
        line-height: 110px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 15px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    
    #borrar {
        background-color: orangered;
    }
```

```html
        <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculadora Interactiva</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body onload="inicio()";>
        <table class = "calculadora">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><span id="result"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="raizCuadrada">2\/''</button></td>
                <td><button id="raizX">x\/''</button></td>
                <td><button id="cuadrado">^2</button></td>
                <td><button id="cubo">^3</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="elevadoX">^x</button></td>
                <td><button id="logaritmo10">log(10)</button></td>
                <td><button id="logaritmoNeperiano">log(e)</button></td>
                <td><button id="logaritmoX">log(x)</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="borrar">C</button></td>
                <td><button id="division">/</button></td>
                <td><button id="multiplicacion">x</button></td>
                <td><button id="resto">%</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="siete">7</button></td>
                <td><button id="ocho">8</button></td>
                <td><button id="nueve">9</button></td>
                <td><button id="resta">-</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="cuatro">4</button></td>
                <td><button id="cinco">5</button></td>
                <td><button id="seis">6</button></td>
                <td><button id="suma">+</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="uno">1</button></td>
                <td><button id="dos">2</button></td>
                <td><button id="tres">3</button></td>
                <td rowspan="2"><button id = "igual">=</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><button id="cero">0</button></td>
                <td><button id="cerocero">00</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Gracias de antemano por la ayuda

Comment: Carles Ferreiro, ha mejorado un poco, tenias razon con que se me ha escapado el break en logX y tambien se me ha escapado en default, pero sigue sin funcionar correctamente, el resultado ha cambiado por lo que algo ha hecho ese break pero no lo ha arreglado

Comment: Triby muchas gracias, ya esta todo arreglado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Parece que estabas haciendo la operación de *Logaritmo* al revés y, probablemente, la confusión es porque creaste una función donde internamente inviertes los parámetros, que ya venían invertidos.

```
// No es necesaria la función, basta con:
fin = Math.log(numero2) / Math.log(numero1);
```

Aparte, para evitar repetir código, puedes asignar clase a los botones con funcionamiento similar:

- Números (00, 0-9): Solo agregan el texto del botón al número actual
- Operadores generales: Finalizan primer número, crean signo y limpian número actual, en espera de un segundo número
- Operadores especiales: Finalizan primer número, crean signo y realizan el cálculo

Obtienes cada grupo de elementos con `document.querySelectorAll('.clase')` y agregas el evento `onclick` dentro de un ciclo.

Después, al resolver, analizas el signo, que debe ser igual al texto que muestra el botón.

```js
    var numero1 = 0;
    var numero2 = 0;
    var signo = "";
    
    function inicio() {
        // Resultado
        var result = document.getElementById("result");
        
        // Numeros
        let numeros = document.querySelectorAll('.num');
        // Operadores que requieren 2 números
        let op1 = document.querySelectorAll('.op1');
        // Operadores que solo necesitan 1 número
        let op2 = document.querySelectorAll('.op2');
    
        // Igual y Reset
        var igual = document.getElementById("igual");
        var borrar = document.getElementById("borrar");
    
        // Recorrer para agregar evento onclick
        numeros.forEach(num => num.addEventListener('click', function() {
            result.textContent += num.innerText;
        }));
        op1.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = btn.innerText;
            limpiar();
        }));
        op2.forEach(btn => btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
            numero1 = result.textContent;
            signo = btn.innerText;
            resolver();
        }));

    
        // Igual y reset
        igual.onclick = function(e) {
            numero2 = result.textContent;
            resolver();
        }
    
        borrar.onclick = function(e) {
            resetearValores();
        }
    }
    
    function limpiar() {
        result.textContent = "";
    }
    
    function resetearValores() {
        result.textContent = "";
        numero1 = 0;
        numero2 = 0;
        signo = "";
    }
    
    function resolver() {
        var fin = 0;
    
        switch(signo) {
            case "+":
                fin = parseFloat(numero1) + parseFloat(numero2);
                break;
            case "-":
                fin = parseFloat(numero1) - parseFloat(numero2);
                break;
            case "x":
                fin = parseFloat(numero1) * parseFloat(numero2);
                break;
            case "/":
                fin = parseFloat(numero1) / parseFloat(numero2);
                break;
            case "%":
                fin = parseFloat(numero1) % parseFloat(numero2);
                break;
            case "2\\/''":
                fin = Math.sqrt(numero1);
                break;
            case "x\\/''":
                fin = Math.pow(numero2, Math.pow(numero1, (-1)));
                break;
            case "^2":
                fin = Math.pow(numero1, 2);
                break;
            case "^3":
                fin = Math.pow(numero1, 3);
                break;
            case "^x":
                fin = Math.pow(numero1, numero2);
                break;
            case "log(10)":
                fin = Math.log10(numero1);
                break;
            case "log(e)":
                fin = Math.log(numero1);
                break;
            case "log(x)":
                fin = Math.log(numero2) / Math.log(numero1);
                break;
            default:
                if(numero1 == 0) {
                    fin = numero2;
                } else {
                    fin = numero1;
                }
        }
        resetearValores();
        result.textContent = fin;
    }
```

```css
    .calculadora {
        display: block;
        margin: 0 auto;
        padding: 20px;
        background-color: #14db2f;
        width: 400px;
        height: 600px;
        border-radius: 20px;
    }
    
    .calculadora td button {
        display: block;
        width: 85px;
        height: 55px;
        font-size: 20px;
        box-align: center;
        border-radius: 5px;
    }
    
    #igual {
        height: 94px;
        width: 85px;
    }
    
    #cero {
        height: 35px;
        width: 174px;
    }
    
    #cerocero {
        height: 35px;
    }
    
    #result {
        display: block;
        font-size: 35px;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
        width:350px;
        height: 120px;
        line-height: 110px;
        background-color: #fff;
        border-radius: 15px;
        overflow-y: auto;
        text-align: right;
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
    
    #borrar {
        background-color: orangered;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title>Calculadora Interactiva</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="estilo.css">
    </head>
    <body onload="inicio()";>
        <table class = "calculadora">
            <tr>
                <td colspan="4"><span id="result"></span></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="raizCuadrada" class="op2">2\/''</button></td>
                <td><button id="raizX" class="op1">x\/''</button></td>
                <td><button id="cuadrado" class="op2">^2</button></td>
                <td><button id="cubo" class="op2">^3</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="elevadoX" class="op1">^x</button></td>
                <td><button id="logaritmo10" class="op2">log(10)</button></td>
                <td><button id="logaritmoNeperiano" class="op2">log(e)</button></td>
                <td><button id="logaritmoX" class="op1">log(x)</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="borrar">C</button></td>
                <td><button id="division" class="op1">/</button></td>
                <td><button id="multiplicacion" class="op1">x</button></td>
                <td><button id="resto" class="op1">%</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="siete" class="num">7</button></td>
                <td><button id="ocho" class="num">8</button></td>
                <td><button id="nueve" class="num">9</button></td>
                <td><button id="resta" class="op1">-</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="cuatro" class="num">4</button></td>
                <td><button id="cinco" class="num">5</button></td>
                <td><button id="seis" class="num">6</button></td>
                <td><button id="suma" class="op1">+</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><button id="uno" class="num">1</button></td>
                <td><button id="dos" class="num">2</button></td>
                <td><button id="tres" class="num">3</button></td>
                <td rowspan="2"><button id="igual">=</button></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="2"><button id="cero" class="num">0</button></td>
                <td><button id="cerocero" class="num">00</button></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    
        <script src="index.js"></script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Sin probarlo, creo que el problema es que te falta un break en el case "logX" y te entra por el default (que precisamente es fin = numero1)

Answer (score 1):

Además de agregar el break en logX, están invertidos los números en la línea de fin:

```
case "logX":
  function getBaseLog(x, y) {
       return Math.log(y) / Math.log(x);
  }  
  fin = getBaseLog(numero1, numero2);
  break;
```